# Is AlarmManager.setTime() is guaranteed to change the System Time?

Tags: android

I developed a Android application can change the System Time.
With permision `Manifest.permission.SET_TIME`,
`AlarmManager.setTime(long millis)` can deal.

but The app don't know if the system time really changed,
cause `setTime(long millis)` returns void.

Is `setTime(long millis)` guaranteed to change the System Time?

```
//example
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Record the time, then call the method to change the time, and then compare